# Extract tar.gz archive into different folders (due to limitations)

Tags: python

here is my original code:

```
import tarfile

file = tarzip.open(r'directory')
file.extractall(r'directory')
```

But I received the exception, because the target folder had limitation to 400k files.

Could you, please, advice me, how to split the extract into 6 different folders (archive has ~1.5m xml files)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've never heard of a `tarzip` module. Did you mean `tarfile`?

Comment: @Sören excuse me, edited :)

Comment: That's why you should **copy** your code, not type it in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all the files in the archive using [`file.getmembers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getmembers) or [`file.getnames()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getnames). Inside the loop use [`file.extract()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extract) to extract the file to wherever you want to.